# Reactjs reload current route when hitting reload button, not the entire application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a basic react-router setup, with Switch, like this:

```
import React from "react"
import {Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"

import AuthenticatedRoute from "./components/AuthenticatedRoute"
import UnauthenticatedRoute from "./components/UnauthenticatedRoute"

import Home from './containers/Home'
import Login from './containers/Login'
import Books from './containers/Books'


import NotFound from './containers/NotFound'


export default ({ childProps }) => (
  <Switch>
    <AuthenticatedRoute path="/" exact component={Home} props={childProps} />
    <UnauthenticatedRoute path="/login" exact component={Login} props={childProps} />
    <AuthenticatedRoute path="/books" exact component={Books} props={childProps} />

    { /* Finally, catch all unmatched routes */ }
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
)
```

and AuthenticatedRoute module like:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default ({ component: C, props: cProps, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      cProps.isAuthenticated
        ? <C {...props} {...cProps} />
        : (
          <Redirect
            to="/login"
          />
)}
  />
)
```

Now, everything is OK, but, when I'm on `/books` route and hit the reload button on browser or <kbd>F5</kbd>, the whole application refreshes, and starts from home page, and I lose my current active route.

How can I preserve my active route when hitting the reload?

Comment: Can you show the entire component with the `Switch` ?

Comment: Updated, showed entire component